# Video Output in Protected/Long Mode

Tags: x86, osdev, vga, protected-mode

I have a question about plotting pixels on screen in protected/long mode and video generation is OS in general.

How I can display something on screen in high resolution, such as 1920*1080, or better for me, in 1680*1050 ( because of my little bit old monitor)?  And how I can make specific driver for my video card - Intel Integrated HD 620 on main computer.

On my dev Server I have some integrated VGA controller on motherboard - Intel 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics controller ( rev 3 ) - I think to control this specific card I just need standard VGA Controller stuff - like it's ports, DAC and so on, but I don't know how to make driver for my external GPU ( I mean not Integrated on motherboard ), which is Fujitsu 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller, and where I can get information about it, and also where can I get information about this whole subject and maybe some tutorial.

Comment: Hey Lukas.  Can you edit your question to ask for one thing specific?   Asking for tutorials is off topic for this site.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions and  [Switching to a higher resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34844039)

Answer (score 1):

> My question is that, how I can display something on screen in high resolution, such as 1920*1080, or better for me, in 1680*1050 ( because of my little bit old monitor), and how I can make specific driver for my video card, and where I can get information about it, and also where can I get information about this whole subject and maybe some tutorial. Thanks very much for your help!

The first problem is setting a usable video mode. For this there are 3 cases:

- use the BIOS/VBE functions. This is easy enough in early boot code, but horribly messy after boot.
- use UEFI functions (GOP, UGA). This is easy in early boot code, but impossible after boot.
- write native video drivers for every possible video card. This is impossible - you can't write drivers for video cards that don't exist yet, so every time a new video card is released there will be no driver for however long it takes to write one (and for "sole developer" you will never have time to write one).

The "most sane" choice is "boot loader sets up default video mode using whatever firmware provides and gives OS details for frame buffer (then native video driver may be used to change video modes after early boot if there ever is a suitable native video driver)".

Note that for all of these cases (BIOS, UEFI and native driver) there's a selection process involved - you want to get information from the monitor describing what it supports, and information from the video card about what it supports, and information from the OS about what it supports; and then use that all the information to find the best video mode that is supported by everything. You don't want to setup a 1920*1600 video mode just because the video card supports it (and then have your old monitor showing a black screen because it doesn't support that specific video mode).

For putting a pixel; the formula is mostly "`address = video_frame_buffer_address + y * bytes_per_line + x * bytes_per_pixel`"; where `video_frame_buffer_address` is the virtual address for wherever you felt like mapping the frame buffer; and the physical address of the frame buffer, and the values for `bytes_per_line` and `bytes_per_pixel`, are details that will come from BIOS or UEFI or a native video driver.

For displaying anything on the screen, putting pixels like this is a huge performance disaster (you don't want the overhead of "`address = video_frame_buffer_address + y * bytes_per_line + x * bytes_per_pixel`" calculation for every pixel). Instead, you want higher level functions (e.g. to draw characters, draw lines, fill rectangles, ...) so that you can calculate a starting address once, then adjust that address as you draw instead of doing the full calculation again. For example; for drawing a rectangle you might end up with something vaguely like "`for each horizontal line in rectangle { memset(address, colour, width); address += bytes_per_line; }`".

However; you should also know that (for increasing the chance that your code will work on more different computers) you will need to support multiple different color depths and pixel formats; and if you have 10 different drawing functions (to draw characters, lines, rectangles, ..) and support 10 different colour depths/pixel formats; then it adds up to a 100 different functions. An easier alternative is to have a generic pixel format (e.g. "32-bit per pixel ARGB") and do all the drawing to a buffer in RAM using that generic pixel format and then have functions to blit data from the buffer in RAM to the frame buffer while converting the data to whatever the video mode actually wants.